# TCL array substitution

Tags: tcl

In TCL (running v8.6.6) I want to create an array with a substitution of one or more of the value of the array with the value of another variable.

If we were in C I will write

```
float a = 10;
float b[4] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
b[2]=a;
```

and if I print on stdout I got 1.0 10.0 3.3 4.0.

In TCL instead I started by a simple exampe. I wrote

```
set a 10.0
set b $a

puts $b
```

I got 10.0 as output, but if I want to do the same in a array so I wrote

```
set a 10.0
set b {1.0 $a 3.0 4.0}

puts $b
```

and I'm expecting

```
1.0 10.0 3.0 4.0
```

but I got

```
-0.5 $a 0.5 0.79
```

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have a look at [the 12 rules of Tcl syntax](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: C indexes from zero (just like Tcl); printing that array should have given `1.0 2.0 10.0 4.0`

Comment: Terminology: An *array* in TCL is, like in awk, an associative array/hash table. You're working with a  *list*, which is more like a C array.

Comment: And what you should be seeing printed by that tcl code is `1.0 $a 3.0 4.0`. What you say your C code prints is different from what should be seen too, though, so there's got to be more going on that you didn't share in the question.

Comment: thanks to everyone for you comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curly brackets `{}` prevent substitution, try:

```
set b [list 1.0 $a 3.0 4.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you've found that *creating* a list with substitutions is done via the `list` command, here's how to do the assignment to an element that is equivalent to `b[2]=a;` from C.

```
lset b 2 $a
```

Comment: This is _technically_ not the answer to what you asked, but it does show what you might've been thinking about.